# Set default parameters for angular pipes

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way (other than creating my own pipe that later uses angular's) to set application wide defaults for an angular pipe?
I'm extensively using the currency pipe like this

```
{{ price | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'0.2-2':'de' }}
```

I don't want to always write all the parameters `:'EUR':'symbol':'0.2-2':'de'` and would rather set them once for all usages of `currency`.

I don't find something about that in the docs - is it possible or do I need my own pipe with defaults?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of angular **pipes** use existing methods to return their transform value , for example if you take a look at the **[currency](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)** pipe you'll see that it uses two method to return the string value of the formatted numer to currency  , **[formatCurrency](https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency)** and **[getCurrencySymbol](https://angular.io/api/common/getCurrencySymbol)**  and they are available in [angular common module](https://angular.io/api/common) so we can use them to build our own version of the **currency** pipe without the need of inheritance or something like that , simply the **currency** pipe return  the return value of **[formatCurrency](https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency)** function and call it with the params passed to the pipe and uses **[getCurrencySymbol](https://angular.io/api/common/getCurrencySymbol)** to get the symbol of a specified **currency code**

so now we can build our own version with default values we specify and here it is

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
  import { formatCurrency, getCurrencySymbol } from '@angular/common';
@Pipe({
    name: 'mycurrency',
})
export class MycurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(
        value: number,
        currencyCode: string = 'EUR',
        display:
            | 'code'
            | 'symbol'
            | 'symbol-narrow'
            | string
            | boolean = 'symbol',
        digitsInfo: string = '0.2-2',
        locale: string = 'en-US',
    ): string | null {
        return formatCurrency(
          value,
          locale,
          getCurrencySymbol(currencyCode, 'wide'),
          currencyCode,
          digitsInfo,
        );
    }
}
```

Now its working perfect

> Note here I am using **en-US** as locale if you need to use other locale such as **de** you need to import it and register,

more info

[angular pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

[CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

[formatCurrency](https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency)

[getCurrencySymnol](https://angular.io/api/common/getCurrencySymbol)

[angular common](https://angular.io/api/common)

Comment: That's true , you can now build you're own version of any angular pipe

Answer (score 8):

Simple as you inject DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE to your providers

```
import { DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE,  } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';
registerLocaleData(localeDe, localeDeExtra);
@NgModule({
providers: [
  {
   provide: LOCALE_ID,
   useValue: 'de'
  },
  {
    provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE,
    useValue: 'EUR'
  }    
 ]
 })
```

Comment: This is a good solution. For new devs you need to set the provider defaults typically in the root module of your app. In the providers sections as shown above.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement something called proxy pipes.

The following snippet demonstrates how to implement a Proxy for Angular’s `CurrencyPipe` :

```
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'currency'
})
export class CurrencyProxyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  currencyPipe = new CurrencyPipe('en')

  transform(value,code = 'EUR',display = 'symbol',digites = '0.3-5',local ='en') {
     return this.currencyPipe.transform(value,code,display,digites,local)
  }

}
```

If you look at the result you will find it is somehow calling currency with default parameters.

```
{{ price | currency }}  // €100.000
{{ price | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'0.3-5' }} // €100.000
```

It somehow looks the similar to the extend currency pipe but this solution I been use in case of set default parameters for angular pipes.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-proxy-pipes)

Happy Coding.

Comment: this is not english, man, I'm sorry. please edit it again or should I do it?

Comment: I prefer this over the accepted answer as I don't want to have to create an entirely new pipe, I want to keep the `currency` pipe, I just don't want it defaulting to USD.

Comment: I used this example and it suddenly stopped working. It turns out when you import the `CommonModule` from angular this proxy pipe isn't used :(

Comment: @devqon have you add the custome pipe in the app.module  ?

Comment: It seems not to work when using feature modules. See this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpsr6t. EDIT: it does seem to work when putting it in a shared module, which seems to be the best practice anyway

Answer (score 5):

Since I believe it's not possible I've extended angular's CurrencyPipe class with below class, using default parameters in `transform`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'deCurrency'
})
export class DeCurrencyPipe extends CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, currencyCode: string = 'EUR', display: 'code' | 'symbol' | 'symbol-narrow' | string | boolean = 'symbol', digitsInfo: string = '0.2-2', locale: string = 'de'): string | null {
    return super.transform(value, currencyCode, display, digitsInfo, locale);
  }
}
```

I'm still very open to suggestions on setting default values without writing my own...

Comment: I'm afraid that's the way to go at the moment

Comment: By looking at the [implementation of currency pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.0.4/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L96-L163) the defaults are coded as parameter defaults so we cannot use some kind of provider or injection to set the dafaults.

Comment: you can see my answer below or just click the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60569746/11166640